# Norm in $C^{1}([0,T];H^{s}(\mathbb R^d))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am reading Evans' PDE textbook and found to prove the existence of solutions to a PDE using a priori estimates, if one chooses the space $X=C([0,T];H^{s}(\mathbb R^d))$, then the norm is defined as $$\|u\|_{X}=\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} \|u\|_{H^s},$$ where $H^s$ is just Sobolev spaces.

My question is how to define the norm for the PDE if we choose $X=C^{1}([0,T];H^{s}(\mathbb R^d))$? Is it $$\|u\|_{X}=\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} \|u\|_{H^s}+\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} \|\partial_{t}u\|_{H^s}$$ or
$$\|u\|_{X}=\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} \|u\|_{H^s}+\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} \|\nabla u\|_{H^s}?$$

Comment: the former seems more natural

Answer (score 3):

The space $C^1([0,T],X)$ is the space of all functions from $[0,T]$ to $X$ that are continuously differentiable. The norm is the $\sup$-norm of the function and its time-derivative. So the first choice is correct. For the second one, there is the possibility of ambiguity as $\nabla$ is typically used to denote derivative with respect to spatial variables, not time.

Comment: $nabla$ here means the space derivatives.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with you since your $C^1$ space is different than mine. Mine is space-time space, not from $[0,T]$ to $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: In my case $X=H^s(\mathbb R^d)$. However, the type of the 'inner' space does not matter at all.

Comment: Not quite. Yours is from $[0,T]$ to $X$ or whatever spaces. I was asking for the space-time. The difference is "," and ";". For example, what is the norm of $L^{p}([0,T]; L^{q}(\Omega))$?

Comment: If you want to have space-time function spaces then you should not use the notation for time-space function spaces. Also in my world, there is not difference between "," and ";" in the definition of those spaces.